# Wrap Entire React Native App With One Font

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, text-styling

I am looking for a simple way of wrapping my entire react native app with one font but I am having trouble finding documentation on the best way to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions or references I can read through? Mostly what I am reading is that I need to make a new Text file and then import the font for each text element which is not what I want to do.

References I have already read through: 
https://medium.com/@fasterpancakes/react-native-row-how-to-wrap-components-and-avoid-stylesheets-99406e068357
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text
https://ospfolio.com/two-way-to-change-default-font-family-in-react-native/

I am looking to do something like this:

```
import {useFonts} from "@use-expo/font";
import {AppLoading} from "expo";
...
const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Raleway-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"),
    "Raleway-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf"),
    "Raleway-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App
        ref={(navigator) => {
          setNavigator(navigator);
        }}
        style={{fontFamily: "Raleway-Bold"}}
      />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just make a custom component with all the default styling you need and then use that everywhere instead of `<Text>`

// DefaultText.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const DefaultText = props => <Text style={styles.defaultText}>{props.children}</Text>;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultText: {
    fontFamily: "Raleway-Bold",
  },
});

export default DefaultText;
```

// SomeComponent.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import DefaultText from "./DefaultText";

const SomeComponent = props => (
  <View>
    <DefaultText>This should be in Raleway-Bold</DefaultText>
  </View>
);

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more simplistic like a wrapper. I have something similar to this -I created a utils folder that contained a reference to the font .ttf and the extension so all I have to do is add Font.Bold to the top level container in every style sheet. Obviously this is a lot of work if you already have built out a lot of components